# Файл в post запросе

Tags: android, java, post

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть код, который отправляет post запрос на сервер. Все работает хорошо, но мне к переменным, которые отправляются на сервер нужно добавить файл.Имя файла и путь - все это есть.

```
   public SERVERPOST(Context context, URL url, Map<String, String> parameters) {
    super("POST", parameters, url);
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ;
    File new_dir = new File(root + "/test/" + filename);
    String path =  new_dir.getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path); // искомый файл

    postParameters.put("login", login);
    postParameters.put("password", password);
```

}

Как мне к двум переменным добавить файл?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044291/using-httppost-to-upload-file-android даже класс есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204476/android-file-uploader-with-server-side-php